# how do i match two scripts to an object in models

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

how do i match the headlines code to the content code for the models in my views.py . it keeps repeating one headline. i have tried to use the save each request. it did not still work. what is wrong? i am new to django so i do not really know alot. each time i scrape i am supposed to get new headlines and the content of those headlines.

[image]

this my views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import django
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "untt.settings")
django.setup()
import requests
import urllib3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import timedelta, timezone, datetime
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

from news.models import Headline, UserProfile


def scrape(request):
    user_p = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
    user_p.last_scrape = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    user_p.save()
    for i in range(1):
        r = requests.get("https://www.dailypost.ng/hot-news/page/{}".format(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
        mydivs = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "mvp-cd-date left relative"})
    for div in mydivs:
        mytags = div.findNext('h2')
        for tag in mytags:
            allheadlines = (tag.strip())

    z = [linkk.get('href', '/') for linkk in soup.find_all("a", {"rel": "bookmark"})]
    for url in z:
        r = requests.get("https://www.dailypost.ng/hot-news/")
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        conteent = soup.find(id="mvp-content-main")
        article = ''
        for i in conteent.findAll('p'):
            article = article + ' ' + i.text

    news_headline = Headline()
    news_headline.title = allheadlines
    news_headline.contentt = article
    news_headline.save()
    return redirect('/')



# Create your views here.
```

this is my models.py

models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


User = get_user_model()

class Headline(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contentt = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_scrape = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.user, self.last_scrape)


def post_user_signup_receiver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    userprofile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(post_user_signup_receiver, sender=User)
```

my urls.py

```
"""untt URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from news.views import scrape


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('scrape/', scrape)
]
```

although ,each headline has a different content when i click it, the headlines are all the same

Comment: The lines for tag in mytags:  allheadlines = (tag.strip()) will only keep the last tag in the headlinwses. is this intented? I would think you need to but the headline saving code into this loop.

Comment: I don't know if save() can be used twice if I do that.

Comment: Whenever you create a new object you can save it. news_headline = Headline() will create a new object.